# Are there any other sites that allow users to search for historic hurricanes within a given area?

Tags: tropical-cyclone

Once upon a time I seem to remember there being a plethora of sites with very graphical interactive tools for quickly searching Atlantic hurricane data by time range, locations impacted, and storm type and get quick answers.  Some I remember as being very intuitive, and offerings from tv stations, government sites, and independents.

These days I know of exactly one, https://coast.noaa.gov/hurricanes/.  However I find this site to be difficult to comparably difficult to navigate in finding the location, filtering, and interpreting.  I believe NOAA once offered a top-notch option at http://hurricane.csc.noaa.gov/hurricanes/, but it's long gone, and I have trouble finding any others.  [There's great such tools that have developed for severe weather](http://www.stormreportmap.com), and perhaps with the millions of sites out there, other good ones for hurricanes exist, and I just don't know it.

Even better would be if such a site also included other basins to boot.  But these days, even for the Atlantic, I usually just look through pages on like [Unisys Weather](http://weather.unisys.com/hurricane/) or [the archives](http://derecho.math.uwm.edu/models/archive/) on [Clark Evans' model website](http://derecho.math.uwm.edu/models/) or [Wikipedia annual maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_hurricane_season).  But searching for "when is the last time a storm affected X" has proven surprisingly hard these days.  Any help to offer?

Comment: http://www.rmcchennaieatlas.tn.nic.in/abouteatlas.aspx. Will you upvote ? :)

Comment: @gansub Takes a bit of work with the registration, but now that I worked through all that, and the "older" interface layout, which is reasonable enough, looks useful beyond that, absolutely.

Comment: (Note that the Coast archive does include some other basins actually)

Comment: The only other useful site I've found thus far is https://www.accuweather.com/en/hurricane/tracker.  It's got fairly limited options really, no real search... but it is nicely simple to plot storms on a more dynamic map at least, and seems nicely lightweight (compared to the frustrating loading of the Coast site), plus a few extra basic plots on current storms.

Comment: (Also of slight use to at least gauge the danger to areas is NHC's climatology page, particularly https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/climo/#returns)

Comment: How about ibtracs and troPyCal ?

Comment: @gansub, I'm familiar with troPyCal (have followed some of the meteorologists involved for a while)... had not heard of ibtracs by name, but looks like the best track dataset?  Certainly sounds like you should make an answer of them (though they may be a bit more involved than being a site, they're useful nonetheless for those looking for such things)

Comment: What ?? You had not heard of IBTrACS before ? https://ibtracs.unca.edu/ . I feel I am Q and you are Picard !

Comment: @gansub haha nope!  I had resorted in recent years (since the loss of Unisys data) to often going through advisories/NHC archive graphics to remind myself of the values over time for past storms.  So yeah, that's a beautiful beautiful website, having the easy tables and graphs... and throwing in things like satellite and wind radii just makes it better.  A bit odd it hasn't updated in a few months, but looks to be a fantastic resource in a very barren existence.

Comment: One day we'll finally see people pull together all the data (sites like https://bmcnoldy.rsmas.miami.edu/tropics/radar/, https://web.uwm.edu/hurricane-models/models/archive/historical.html, the NHC TC report ob tables, etc).  In a nice, comfortable format for everyday folks.  One can dream!  Then again, given the plot of min SLP I saw in a tropycal post at your nudging, maybe a lot of that is finally finding its place there.  I'll have to explore that more too, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is this atlas for the North Indian Ocean basin - [Indian Ocean Cyclone Atlas](http://www.rmcchennaieatlas.tn.nic.in/abouteatlas.aspx) and while I am not sure about the cyclone tracks for the pre satellite era cyclones the site is comprehensive and covers all cyclones in the Indian Ocean up to the current period. After you register yourself here - [Registration](http://www.rmcchennaieatlas.tn.nic.in/Registration.aspx)  then you can view the cyclone tracks.

Here is a sample of cyclone tracks between 2012 and 2016

[image]